# Executar Método Java de Tempo em Tempo - Executar Periodicamente

Tags: java, thread, scheduler

Como faço para executar um método de uma classe Java de x em x tempo no WebLogic?

Pelo que estive a verificar, existe a possibilidade de utilizar a anotação @Schedule no método (Java EE 6). Mas como estou a utilizar Java EE 5, esta anotação não funciona. Existe outra forma de fazer sem ser com a anotação @Schedule?

Comment: Alcofra, se possível [edite a questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/67086/edit) e coloque mais informações a respeito do que você quer fazer, do jeito que está é muito ampla. Esse artigo [Invoking Web Services from Client Applications and WebLogic Server](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webserv/client.html) deve ajudar em algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já tive que fazer algo muito semelhante ao que você está solicitando. Dentro do servidor de aplicação **WebLogic 10.3** de **10 em 10 segundos** conectar em um Tópico JMS e consumir mensagens deste tópico. Eu tive que fazer isso dentro do servidor do WebLogic, e não utilizei recursos diretamente da plataforma Java EE, e sim da SE(Java SE).

Bom, há duas maneiras, a primeira é no **Startup** da sua aplicação criar um **callback**

ou

NO EJB que vai fazer a chamada para o método que inicializa, se é que você tem um. Você cria um método com a anotação **[@PostContruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html)**, este método será chamado como **callback** da criação do seu **EJB**.

Tanto no **callback** do Startup do WebLogic quanto no da criação do EJB você cria um Pool com uma Thread ou mais, que vai executar sua lógica de acessar serviços ou executar seus métodos de negócio. Este Pool é um pool especializado que vai em periodicamente executar suas tarefas, aqui está o exemplo:

```
public static void main(String... args){

ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture =
    scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Callable() {
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Executed!");
            return "Called!";
        }
    },
    10,
    TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

No código acima um Pool é criado com uma Thread, e uma tarefa, que no caso é uma instancia de **Callable** - Sendo executada de 10 em 10 Segundos.

Considere o Método **shutdown**

No caso do EJB, você pode definir um método preDestroy, que deve ser anotado com a anotação **@PreDestroy** - assim, você pode parar a execução. Para isso, use o método Shutdown

```
scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
```

Este é o Executors Framework, um Framework poderoso da Plataforma Java, adicionada na versão 1.5 SE.

Por favor leia os Javadocs da Classe: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda Filipe. Era mesmo isso que eu queria.