# Como executar um programa em java diariamente em um determinado horário de maneira automatica

Tags: java, java-8

Ola, preciso executar um programa em java diariamente em um determinado horário, achei algumas coisas sobre timer.schedule, porém gostaria de ver alguns exemplos, obrigado!

Comment: Esta pergunta já foi respondida aqui no stack, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67086/executar-m%C3%A9todo-java-de-tempo-em-tempo-executar-periodicamente/67963#67963

Comment: Isso vai depender se o seu programa roda em desktop ou web.

Comment: @Shura16 por que depende?

Comment: A resposta do colega Emir Marques mostra bem. O funcionamento das tecnologias é um pouco diferente.

Comment: quem marcou como duplicada saiba q a resposta postada na outra sessão utiliza um bat e tarefas agendadas do windows, solução porca!

Answer (score 4):

**Aplicação web:**

```
 public  class EnviaEmail implements Job {
      public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
        System.out.println("enviando email para evisar mudanca de senha...");
        // acessar api de e-mail aqui
      }   
    }
```

Se quisermos que esse procedimento seja executado uma vez por dia, à meia noite, utilizamos a API do Quartz:

```
SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();

JobDetail job = new JobDetail("dispara_email", "grupo", EnviaEmail.class);
Trigger aMeiaNoite = TriggerUtils.makeDailyTrigger(0, 0);
sched.scheduleJob(job, aMeiaNoite);

sched.start();
```

Poderíamos também ter usado expressões no formato do cron, usando o CronTrigger, como por exemplo acionar o Job a cada 20 segundos:

```
CronTrigger trigger = 
   new CronTrigger("20_segundos", "grupo", "0/20 * * * * ?");
```

A classe EnviaEmail será então instanciada a meia noite, e terá seu método execute(JobExecutionContext context) invocado.

Há também outras alternativas ao próprio Quartz para agendamento de tarefa. Uma delas é subverter o Hudson, utilizando-o não apenas como servidor de integração contínua, mas também para gerenciar suas tarefas, aproveitando suas características, gerenciamento de log das falhas e UI. Ou até mesmo usar o cron diretamente disparando requisições através de curl ou similar. No Google App Engine, por exemplo, há um serviço de cron próprio que funciona de maneira similar, disparando requests para determinada URL no momento agendado.

Fonte: http://blog.caelum.com.br/agendamento-de-tarefas-em-aplicacoes-web-um-truque-com-quartz/

**Aplicação desktop:**

No caso de aplicação desktop você pode usar o próprio agendador de tarefas do SO para rodar um arquivo jar em determinado horário. Para tal você pode criar um arquivo .bat colocar um código similar ao abaixo:

```
javaw -Xmx200m -jar C:\Path\to\jarfile\TheJar.jar
```

Note que existe um caminho que aponta para o diretório do jar. Então esse bat pode ser cadastrado no agendador de tarefas.

Para ser cadastrado, no Windows por exemplo, siga os passos abaixo:

**Clique em Iniciar > Todos os Programas > Acessórios > Ferramentas do Sistema > Tarefas Agendadas**

1. Duplo clique em Adicionar Tarefa Agendada para iniciar o Wizard de
   adição de tarefas, e então clique em próximo na primeira caixa de
   diálogo.
2. A próxima caixa de diálogo mostra a lista de programas que estão
   instaladas no seu computador, tanto os que fazem parte do sistema do
   Windows XP ou algum programa que foi instalado.
3. Utilize um destes procedimentos:

   Se o programa que você quer rodar está listado, clique no programa e
   então clique em próximo. Se você quer rodar um programa, um script,
   um documento ou mesmo um arquivo .bat que não está listado, clique
   em Abrir, depois clique no diretório e no arquivo que você quer
   agendar.
4. Digite o nome da tarefa e então escolha uma das seguintes opções:

   Diariamente Semanalmente Mensalmente Apenas uma vez  Quando o
   computador iniciar (antes do usuário logar) Quando eu logar
5. Clique em próximo, especifique a informação sobre o dia e hora que
   você deseja que a tarefa seja executada e então clique em próximo.
6. Digite o nome e a senha do usuário que está associado a tarefa. É
   preciso selecionar um usuário que possua permissão para executar
   aquela tarefa. Por padrão o Wizard seleciona o nome do usuário
   logado no momento.
7. Clique em próximo e verifique se todas as configurações estão como
   desejado.

Comment: vou tentar a segunda opção ja que minha aplicação é desktop. obrigado vamos ver se da certo ^^

Comment: A segunda solução não é a mais indicada, ja que se trata de uma aplicação de grande porte, só para constar utilizei o quartz.

Comment: Legal, particularmente também preciso a utilização do QUARTZ

Comment: eh bem legal o quartz, agora estou enfrentando outros problemas, na hora de gerar o runnable jar como utilizo sql server estou tendo problemas com as dependências do maven.

Comment: Preste atenção no teu pom.xml se as dependências estão com a flag scope. Pesquise sobre no google e se precisar da um toque

Comment: valeu Emir Marques ta resolvido, o jdbc sql server não tem em repositório publico, dei um jeito aqui baixando a dependência e criando repositório local